# Extending C1 Image Type with fields for Photographer etc?

Tags: c1-cms

Is it possible to extend the Image type in Composite C1 in order to get fields for photographer and other stuff?

(If not, I'll probably settle for json in the Description field.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain a little bit your question ? I would like to answer as per my understanding.

So in my notion you are trying to get user values using input fields regarding your image ? If yes then answer is yes you can through razor or any kind of function provided by CMS and for that you need to define parameters like this :

```
public DataReference<IMediaFile> ImageSource { get; set; }
public string altText { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

[FunctionParameter(Label = "Short Description",
                   Help = "A short description ...",
                   DefaultValue = "(write your description here)",
                   WidgetMarkup = "<f:widgetfunction name='Composite.Widgets.String.TextArea' xmlns:f='http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0'><f:param name='SpellCheck' value='true' /></f:widgetfunction>")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

So as Shown in above example using [FunctionParameter()] you can set label etc for the rest of the input parameters as well. So this will get the required info from the user and then with the help of razor you can create your `<img>` element. Let me know if we are on the same page as your question, then i think i can provide more light on the answer.

Hope this helps.
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to extend the IMediaFile such that I in the Media Library can have a custom field for Photographer.